# Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpMethodNotAllowedException: Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, axios, http-headers, slim

I'm trying to implement firebase auth in my chrome extension and in my slim php REST API. After some configuration with the extension manifest and with the php server code I have a problem with the token verification. I always get this error when I try to pass the token I get from `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpMethodNotAllowedException: Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET
```

The problem is that I'm using the get method on client side. My axios code is this:

```
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/keygen', {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authToken}`
        }
      })
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response, response.data);
        this.password = response.data.generated_password;
        this.createdPassword = response.data.generated_password;
      });
```

and on the server side I have this code:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;


require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

//I'm adding headers because I'm on localhost and I have a CORS error if I don't specify the chrome ectension id from witch the requests come from. This problem will not occur on live server
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://oegddbimpfdpbojkmfibkebnagidflfc");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$rawPublicKeys = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com');
$keys = json_decode($rawPublicKeys, true);

$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    //"ignore" => [""]
    "secret" => $keys,
    "header" => "X-Authorization",
    "regexp" => "/Bearer\s+(.*)$/i",
    "algorithm" => ["RS256"],
]));

$app->get('/keygen', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){  
    $password = bin2hex(random_bytes(3));
    $response->getBody()->write( json_encode(['generated_password' => $password]) );
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
});
```

How I can fix this? I want to auth the user using firebase and identity api before give the user the ability to make requests to my api endopints. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

I've modified the php code following the slim provided documentation and now this issue seems solved but I get 401 error. I will post another question for this issue

new code

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($request, $handler) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'chrome-extension://oegddbimpfdpbojkmfibkebnagidflfc')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});

$rawPublicKeys = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com');
$keys = json_decode($rawPublicKeys, true);

$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    //"ignore" => [""]
    "secret" => $keys,
    "header" => "X-Authorization",
    "regexp" => "/Bearer\s+(.*)$/i",
    "algorithm" => ["RS256"],
]));

$app->get('/keygen', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){  
    $password = bin2hex(random_bytes(3));
    $response->getBody()->write( json_encode(['generated_password' => $password]) );
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
});

$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response) {
    throw new HttpNotFoundException($request);
});
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528956/slim-framework-method-not-allowed-method-not-allowed-must-be-one-of-post) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by OPTIONS request that is made from localhost during development. Since I didn't configured any endpoint to accept OPTIONS requests, I've solved the issue with a middleware that is managing CORS.

Answer (score 1):

It must be the assigned route for any request has been assigned as GET, but you may be going with other method rather than GET, please check once if there is any time of mismatch in the Route.

For alternate solution you can also mention the Route as **any**, as:

```
Route::any('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

Comment: is this solution slim 4 related?